# How to make Regular Expression take negative numbers into account?

Tags: regex, codemirror

At my work place we're using CodeMirror2 on some legacy tool we're struggling to phase out. So while we're trying to get rid of it we have to maintain certain parts of it.

I'm having trouble understanding a fairly long regular expression that is used to identify decimal numbers, and I need to either adjust that or add something similar for negative numbers.

The regex in question is:

```
new RegExp(/^(?:[-+]i|[-+](?:(?:(?:\d+#+\.?#*|\d+\.\d*#*|\.\d+#*|\d+)(?:[esfdl][-+]?\d+)?)|\d+#*\/\d+#*)i|[-+]?(?:(?:(?:\d+#+\.?#*|\d+\.\d*#*|\.\d+#*|\d+)(?:[esfdl][-+]?\d+)?)|\d+#*\/\d+#*)@[-+]?(?:(?:(?:\d+#+\.?#*|\d+\.\d*#*|\.\d+#*|\d+)(?:[esfdl][-+]?\d+)?)|\d+#*\/\d+#*)|[-+]?(?:(?:(?:\d+#+\.?#*|\d+\.\d*#*|\.\d+#*|\d+)(?:[esfdl][-+]?\d+)?)|\d+#*\/\d+#*)[-+](?:(?:(?:\d+#+\.?#*|\d+\.\d*#*|\.\d+#*|\d+)(?:[esfdl][-+]?\d+)?)|\d+#*\/\d+#*)?i|(?:(?:(?:\d+#+\.?#*|\d+\.\d*#*|\.\d+#*|\d+)(?:[esfdl][-+]?\d+)?)|\d+#*\/\d+#*))(?=[()\s;"]|$)/i);
```

I'm tempted just add `-?` to the beginning like so:

```
new RegExp(/^-?(?:[-+]i|[-+](?:(?:(?:\d+#+\.?#*|\d+\.\d*#*|\.\d+#*|\d+)(?:[esfdl][-+]?\d+)?)|\d+#*\/\d+#*)i|[-+]?(?:(?:(?:\d+#+\.?#*|\d+\.\d*#*|\.\d+#*|\d+)(?:[esfdl][-+]?\d+)?)|\d+#*\/\d+#*)@[-+]?(?:(?:(?:\d+#+\.?#*|\d+\.\d*#*|\.\d+#*|\d+)(?:[esfdl][-+]?\d+)?)|\d+#*\/\d+#*)|[-+]?(?:(?:(?:\d+#+\.?#*|\d+\.\d*#*|\.\d+#*|\d+)(?:[esfdl][-+]?\d+)?)|\d+#*\/\d+#*)[-+](?:(?:(?:\d+#+\.?#*|\d+\.\d*#*|\.\d+#*|\d+)(?:[esfdl][-+]?\d+)?)|\d+#*\/\d+#*)?i|(?:(?:(?:\d+#+\.?#*|\d+\.\d*#*|\.\d+#*|\d+)(?:[esfdl][-+]?\d+)?)|\d+#*\/\d+#*))(?=[()\s;"]|$)/i);
```

This does appear to work, but without understanding what is going in the rest of the regex I'm hesitant to just add it.

So, three questions:

1. What is going on in this regex?
2. Is my approach to extend this to negative numbers a safe approach?
3. Is there an alternate approach I should take?

Comment: are you talking about this codemirror version https://codemirror.net/2/?

Comment: Yes, the [scheme.js](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/search?q=decimalMatcher&unscoped_q=decimalMatcher) file seems to have the relevant piece.